# android async load list from xml

Tags: android

i'm loading a xml data from url and bind it to a list.
the process take some second and the view is freze.
i want to implement the code with async task so it will load in background or show a progress dialog.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

public class XmlActivity extends ListActivity {
    private class LoadDataTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object> {
        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(final Object... urls) {
            fillData();

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final Object result) {
            closeDialog();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            showDialog();
        }
    }

    private NumbersDataSource datasource;
    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    public void fillData() {

        datasource = new NumbersDataSource(this);
        datasource.open();

        List<Number> values = datasource.getAllNumbers();
        datasource.close();

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        String xml = XMLfunctions
                .getXML("http://www.xxxxxx.com/products.xml");
        Document doc = XMLfunctions.XMLfromString(xml);

        NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");

        String temp = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            Element e = (Element) nodes.item(i);
            map.put("category", XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "category"));
            map.put("title", XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "title"));
            map.put("description", XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "description"));
            map.put("pubDate", XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "pubDate"));
            map.put("link", XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "link"));

            String str2array = XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "description");
            String[] arr = str2array.split(",");

            String tempResults = "";
            for (int x = 0; x < arr.length; x++) {
                String tempWin = arr[x].trim();

                Iterator<Number> itr = values.iterator();
                while (itr.hasNext()) {

                    Number number = (Number) itr.next();

                    tempResults += number.hasWin(tempWin);

                }

            }
            if (tempResults.equals(""))
                map.put("results", getText(R.string.no_win).toString());
            else
                map.put("results", getText(R.string.win).toString());

            if (temp == "") {
                temp = XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "pubDate");
            }

            if (temp.equals(XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "pubDate"))) {
                mylist.add(map);
            }

        }

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist,
                R.layout.xml_row_list, new String[] { "category", "title",
                        "description", "pubDate", "results" }, new int[] {
                        R.id.item_category, R.id.item_title,
                        R.id.item_description, R.id.item_pubDate,
                        R.id.item_link });

        setListAdapter(adapter);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.xml_list);
        // fillData();
        new LoadDataTask().execute();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // fillData();
    }

    private void closeDialog() {
        if (dialog != null) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    private void showDialog() {
        if (dialog != null && !dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            dialog.setMessage("Loading. Please wait...");
            dialog.show();
        }
    }
}
```

the  ProgressDialog  in fillData is never shown.
and i get an error

```
03-19 21:13:38.535: E/AndroidRuntime(1669): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
03-19 21:13:38.535: E/AndroidRuntime(1669): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
03-19 21:13:38.535: E/AndroidRuntime(1669):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
03-19 21:13:38.535: E/AndroidRuntime(1669):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
03-19 21:13:38.535: E/AndroidRuntime(1669):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
03-19 21:13:38.535: E/AndroidRuntime(1669):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
03-19 21:13:38.535: E/AndroidRuntime(1669):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
03-19 21:13:38.535: E/AndroidRuntime(1669):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
03-19 21:13:38.535: E/AndroidRuntime(1669):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
03-19 21:13:38.535: E/AndroidRuntime(1669):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
03-19 21:13:38.535: E/AndroidRuntime(1669): Caused by: android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
03-19 21:13:38.535: E/AndroidRuntime(1669):     at android.view.ViewRoot.checkThread(ViewRoot.java:3035)
03-19 21:13:38.535: E/AndroidRuntime(1669):     at android.view.ViewRoot.requestLayout(ViewRoot.java:637)
03-19 21:13:38.535: E/AndroidRuntime(1669):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8320)
03-19 21:13:38.535: E/AndroidRuntime(1669):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8320)
03-19 21:13:38.535: E/AndroidRuntime(1669):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8320)
03-19 21:13:38.535: E/AndroidRuntime(1669):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8320)
03-19 21:13:38.535: E/AndroidRuntime(1669):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8320)
03-19 21:13:38.535: E/AndroidRuntime(1669):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8320)
03-19 21:13:38.535: E/AndroidRuntime(1669):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8320)
03-19 21:13:38.535: E/AndroidRuntime(1669):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8320)
03-19 21:13:38.535: E/AndroidRuntime(1669):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8320)
03-19 21:13:38.535: E/AndroidRuntime(1669):     at android.view.View.setFlags(View.java:4694)
03-19 21:13:38.535: E/AndroidRuntime(1669):     at android.view.View.setVisibility(View.java:3169)
03-19 21:13:38.535: E/AndroidRuntime(1669):     at android.widget.AdapterView.updateEmptyStatus(AdapterView.java:727)
03-19 21:13:38.535: E/AndroidRuntime(1669):     at android.widget.AdapterView.checkFocus(AdapterView.java:697)
03-19 21:13:38.535: E/AndroidRuntime(1669):     at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:486)
03-19 21:13:38.535: E/AndroidRuntime(1669):     at android.app.ListActivity.setListAdapter(ListActivity.java:265)
03-19 21:13:38.535: E/AndroidRuntime(1669):     at com.balabush.pais.XmlActivity.fillData(XmlActivity.java:109)
03-19 21:13:38.535: E/AndroidRuntime(1669):     at com.balabush.pais.XmlActivity$LoadDataTask.doInBackground(XmlActivity.java:23)
03-19 21:13:38.535: E/AndroidRuntime(1669):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
03-19 21:13:38.535: E/AndroidRuntime(1669):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
03-19 21:13:38.535: E/AndroidRuntime(1669):     ... 4 more
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is complete code:

```
package com.db.share;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.sax.Element;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
ndroid.widget.SimpleAdapter;

public class XmlActivity extends ListActivity
{
    private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object>
    {
        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(final Object... urls)
        {
            fillData();

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final Object result)
        {
            closeDialog();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            showDialog();
        }
    }
    private NumbersDataSource datasource;

    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    public void fillData()
    {

        datasource = new NumbersDataSource(this);
        datasource.open();

        final List<Number> values = datasource.getAllNumbers();
        datasource.close();

        final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        final String xml = XMLfunctions.getXML("http://www.xxxxx.com/products.xml");
        final Document doc = XMLfunctions.XMLfromString(xml);

        final NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");

        final String temp = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++)
        {
            final HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            final Element e = (Element) nodes.item(i);
            map.put("category", XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "category"));
            map.put("title", XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "title"));
            map.put("description", XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "description"));
            map.put("pubDate", XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "pubDate"));
            map.put("link", XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "link"));

        }

        final ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist, R.layout.xml_row_list, new String[] { "category",
                "title", "description", "pubDate", "link" }, new int[] { R.id.item_category, R.id.item_title,
                R.id.item_description, R.id.item_pubDate, R.id.item_link });

        setListAdapter(adapter);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.xml_list);

        new DownloadTask().execute();

    }

    private void closeDialog()
    {
        if (dialog != null)
        {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    private void showDialog()
    {
        if (!dialog.isShowing())
        {
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            dialog.setMessage("Loading. Please wait...");
            dialog.show();

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: 03-18 22:28:06.475: E/AndroidRuntime(24920): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.balabush.pais/com.balabush.pais.XmlActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Fixed version: private void showDialog()
    {
        if (dialog != null && !dialog.isShowing())
        {
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            dialog.setMessage("Loading. Please wait...");
            dialog.show();

        }

    }

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to call `fillData()` only in one method [onCreate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) or [onResume()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).
2. You need to do all your "hard & long operations" like loading data in separated thread, for this use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: this is what i asked, how to change the code so it work async?

Answer (score 0):

You have no where used the Async Task as per your code. Anyways if you move the filldata() xml parsing part to the doinbackground() of Asynctask  and call the progress before executing it then your progress bar dialog will work properly. And it must be calling the dismiss() in onPostExecute().